# Finding a sub array based on a given number

Tags: arrays, dynamic-arrays

I’ve an array of numbers and want to get a sub array with length of 4 from it based on a given number. Base array looks like this:

```
const numbers = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110];
```

Few examples of what I want to achieve.

```
const num = 1;
// new array should be
[1, 10, 20, 30];
```

```
const num = 20;
// new array should still be
[1, 10, 20, 30];
```

```
const num = 30;
// new array should be
[30, 40, 50, 60];
```

So if the given number is equal or greater than any fourth number from the base array (but smaller then the subsequent fourth number) then the sub array should start from that number. So in the case above it’s 30, same goes for 60 and 90.
There is also a possibility that given number won’t be a number contained in the base array, example:

```
const num = 54;
// new array should be
[30, 40, 50, 60];
```

And so on for the rest of the numbers. So far I’ve tried to calculate it using `slice` but I’m not sure how to get start and end values programmatically.

Comment: Unclear... Why doesn't `const num = 30;` give `[1, 10, 20, 30];` ? What are the exact rules for selecting sub-array?

Comment: I’ve edited my question, basically the rule is: if the given number is equal to any fourth number from the base array then the sub array should start from that number. So sub arrays should start with 1, 30, 60 or 90.

Comment: Still don't get the rule.... Your description keeps mentiong **"any fourth number"** and then you say **" So sub arrays should start with 1, 30, 60 or 90."**. Element number 4 has the value 30 so that may make sense. However, the value 60 is in element **7** and the value 90 is in element **10**. I can't see how that is related to **"any fourth number"**. As long as the rule is unclear it is impossible to write it as code.